# $a^2+b^2+c^2 +d^2 = ab+bc+bd+da$ implies $a=b=c=d$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, contest-math

I suppose this is an elementary Math Olympiad Question, but i can't think of how to start.

> Question: Let $a,b,c,d$ be real numbers and $a^2+b^2+c^2+d^2=ab+bc+cd+da$.
>   Prove that $a=b=c=d$.

Some simple observation:

- the other direction, that $a=b=c=d$ implies the equality is very easy.
- that might be related to the AM-Gm inequality: $ab \le \frac{a^2+ b^2}{2}$: so we have 
  $$a^2 +b^2 +c^2 + d^2 \ge 2ab + 2cd.$$
  But I cannnot see how this is bigger than $ab+bc+cd+da$. And this only give me an inequality.

Any help/hints would be appreciated!

Comment: Show us what you've tried!

Answer (score 5):

it is equivalent to
$$(a-b)^2+(b-c)^2+(c-d)^2+(a-d)^2=0$$
it follws that $$a^2+b^2+c^2+d^2\geq ab+bc+cd+da$$ for all real numbers $a,b,c,d$

Comment: Wouldn't there be a bunch of 2s?

Comment: Good answer....

Comment: But how can we get to our final answer using this

Comment: @Gaffney Yes, but you can cancel them out.

Comment: @user510006 A sum of squares can only be zero if all the squares are zero.

Comment: expand this and you Can cancel all $2s$

Comment: For a more general statement, see the [rearrangement inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rearrangement_inequality).

Comment: Thanks for the answer

Comment: nice that i could help you!!

Comment: I just did straight matrix congruence over the rationals, got the less attractive three term sum $$  \frac{1}{4} \; \left( 2a - b - d \right)^2 \; + \;   \frac{1}{12} \; \left( 3b - 2c - d \right)^2 \; + \;  \frac{2}{3} \; \left(c-d \right)^2   $$ which gives the same conclusion. Sylvester's Law of Inertia says one of the eigenvalues is zero...

Comment: Right, the invisible term is $0 \; d^2$ so not worth writing